# How to put exception for .isalnum()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the unwanted special symbols from my string in a list by using .isalnum() function in looping through each character in the words and I use the condition for putting exception for apostrophe symbol for cases, like "can't", "didn't", "won't". But it also keeps this symbol for the cases I don't need like " ' ", " 'cant", " 'hello' ". Is there a way to keep just for when the symbol is in the middle of the words?

```py
data_set = "Hello WOrld &()*hello world ////dog /// cat world hello can't "

split_it = data_set.lower().split()
new_word = ''
new_list = list()
for word in split_it:
    new_word = ''.join([x for x in word if x.isalnum() or x == " ' "])
    new_list.append(new_word)

print(new_list)
```

['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'dog', '', 'cat', 'world', 'hello', "can't"]

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: So you don't want to remove the apostrophe in `can't` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh exactly

Comment: @AKX I have already updated the expected output with the word "can't"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all of the characters you don't want, you could use `.strip()` to only remove them from the start and end:

```py
>>> words = "Hello WOrld &()*hello world ////dog /// cat world hello can't ".lower().split()
>>> cleaned_words = [word.strip("&()*/") for word in words]
>>> print(cleaned_words)
['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'dog', '', 'cat', 'world', 'hello', "can't"]
```

Otherwise, you'll probably want a regexp that matches any character except those whitelisted, anchored to the start or end of the string, and then use `re.sub()` to remove them:

```
>>> import re
>>> nonalnum_at_edge_re = re.compile(r'^[^a-z0-9]+|[^a-z0-9]+$', re.I)
>>> cleaned_words = [re.sub(nonalnum_at_edge_re, '', word) for word in words]
['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'dog', '', 'cat', 'world', 'hello', "can't"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression that matches any character that isn't either a lowercase letter or number, and either doesn't have such a character before it (start of word) or after it (end of word):

```
import re

phrase = "Hello WOrld &()*hello world ////dog /// cat world hello can't "

regex = re.compile(r'(?<![a-z0-9])([^a-z0-9])|([^a-z0-9])(?![a-z0-9])')

print([re.sub(regex, '', word) for word in phrase.lower().split()])
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'dog', '', 'cat', 'world', 'hello', "can't"]
```

Comment: That looks a complicated regex, could you break it down please

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It basically matches all cases where you have something that isn't a lowercase letter or a number, *and* there is either no lowercase letter or number before it, or after it. There is probably a better way to do it, though; see *AKX*'s answer.

Comment: Okay what does `?<!` and `?!` signify?

Comment: My regex knowledge isn't that big, but this seems to work too: `re.compile(r'(?<![a-z0-9])([^a-z0-9])')`, which looks a bit simpler.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Those are negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions (basically, they say "match me if this doesn't appear before me" and "match me if this doesn't appear after me".